# admin site as folder inside asp.net site

Tags: asp.net, iis

Now I'm working with ASP.NET (web forms) and Admin for this site is site itself, but located in folder inside existing site. I have some impression that it's not very good, for example if you publish external site with option "delete existing files", it deleted internal site. My question: is it okay if one site located inside another, or I should move it?

Let me paraphrase question: is it bad or good practice to have nested sites or nested projects?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I cannot give you an official answer.
Just as you don't feel right about it so do I.
Publishing websites in nested existing website folder is just not a good idea especially with admin site.

However if for some reason the Admin site has to be inside of the existing site, then it would make sense to make the admin site part of the existing site project so you just publish one project.

Comment: okay, it's not good have nested sites, but what about nested projects: code of another project physically located in folder inside main project. Should they be at the same level?

Answer (score 1):

There is no right or wrong answer, so here is my two cents.

It is fine having another website inside a website as long as you can figure out the web.config. (Sometimes, inside web.configs collide with outside one)

It is fine as long as you are not hosting in Azure. The problem in Azure is you will have to put them in a same package.

Only draw back is as you said you cannot publish application straight from VS using `delete existing files` option.

### Case Study

One of the popular open source shopping cart - [nopcommerce](http://www.nopcommerce.com/) have two separate Web Applications - Nop.Web and Nop.Admin.

It lets you place Admin site under Admin folder if you want Admin features.

Comment: I see in nopcommerce we have Administration folder, containing Nop.Admin project located inside Nop.Web folder, where located Nop.Web project. So projects are actually nested. But I'm not sure how they should be published. Should they be one inside another?

Comment: Yes, they are published one at a time manually. In other words, Nop.Web is published first, then Web.Admin is published.

Answer (score 1):

I'm going to come out and say this is worth avoiding in general and moreover you can get the same outside effect (nested urls) without the hassles of having web configs inside of web configs.

What I would do is build separate sites and if I wanted things to appear to be nested I would use a reverse proxy (which can easily be IIS using [ARR](http://www.iis.net/downloads/microsoft/application-request-routing) running on the same box) to front things and manage public urls.